# Oh no! Yet another number series... - Find the pattern in the two examples and provide an extension

Tags: mathematics, pattern, number-sequence

*Because these have been so successful in the past, I had to bring up my own. In fact, this puzzle was **inspired by [Find the next number](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/5494/find-the-next-number)** even though I (and I guess everybody but the author) still don't know the intended solution yet. Anyway, here it is:*

---

### The puzzle

The British inventor **Jackemias Muff** invented (and build) a number-evolving machine in **1817**. (It was a cold, windy winter's day in Manchester, the Sunday before boxing-day.) You could feed it with any number, and it would produce an unambiguously determined, endless series of follow-up numbers.

For example, if you feed it with "8" you would get

> **8,5,10,14,23,36,47,59,70,78,84,96,...**

If you feed it with "28" instead, you would get

> **28,12,19,28,41,51,61,71,83,96,...**

Can you *explain* how his machine works and build a copy?

> **Victory condition: A correct answer is able to reproduce both series starting from the same seed values and can successfully predict the
>   next number in each series.**

I do not have proof that Muff's machine is unique, although I believe it is.

I will add hints over time, one is given as a starter:

> In 1817, computers have not yet been invented. (Well, 'computer' was
>   still a job-description those days..)

Comment: Just going for the victory condition: `var input = window.prompt('Feed me'); var output = []; output[8] = '8,5,10,14,23,36,47,59,70,78,84,96,'; output[28] = '28,12,19,28,41,51,61,71,83,96,'; while (true) console.log( output[ input ] );` :-)

Comment: @Joe So you predict that the next numbers are...?

Comment: @No.7892142 the number you input. It just loops. Before anyone gets upset, there's a reason it's a comment and not an answer ;-)

Comment: +1 for not just skipping any number-series puzzle. ;-) (But wrong answer ;->)

Comment: @BmyGuest Would telling whether the date has a relevance be too much of a hint?

Comment: @BmyGuest how sure are you that there is only one unique solution to this?

Comment: @No.7892142 It is my plan to reveal this during the follow-up hints, but I will give people at least a 24hrs period to solve it without. (Just to be fair on time-zones.)

Comment: @skv: :c) Pretty, actually. But I will accept any valid solution and I would LOVE to see one which isn't mine.

Comment: The Sunday before Boxing Day? That would be the Sunday before Christmas (Sunday, December 21st, 1817), so why specifically Boxing Day?

Comment: @SQB: Decoy only. One of the later hints would have gone rid of it. But I wanted a reference to ENGLISH as it only works in this language.

Comment: I think it was the first random machine :p

Comment: @kokbira except that from the next number onward both series would be the same...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The sequence is generated as follows:

> Each consecutive term is except for the first (5 and 12 respectively) term is made by adding 1 and the length of the text representation of the current number to the current number. The 5 and 12 are made by simply counting the length of the text representation of the first term.

Thus

> Next terms will be 107

First sequence:

> 8 -> "eight" -> 5 
> 5 -> 5 + len("five") + 1 -> 10 
> 10 + len("ten") + 1 -> 14 
> 14 + len("fourteen") + 1 -> 23 
> Next steps are obvious.

Comment: I knew it would be too easy :c)

Comment: Nicely spotted!

Comment: @BmyGuest It was one of those which you either solve on the spot or you don't at all. Nice one though :)

Comment: a machine that counts keys, computes adding by 1 and shows the result with other keys representing digits... in 1817... ok

Comment: @kokbira as with most machines from that time: when you opened the cupboard underneath you'd have found an Indian dwarf with a big brain and a fast handwriting....

Comment: @BmyGuest oh yeah, like The Turk http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Turk

Comment: @BmyGuest also only one Google result for "Jackemias Muff" (without quotes!) that is this question :)

Comment: @BmyGuest is "Jackemias Muff" some sort of reference to something?

Comment: @dmg or a typo. Too bad they aren't real words, it would have been a Googlewhack!